# Vulkan:How to get values from VkBuffer using VulkanMmoryAllocator

Tags: c++, vulkan

I create a compute shader using vulkan.
I don't understand how to get values from VkBuffer.

```
//create allocator
VmaAllocatorCreateInfo allocator_create_info = {};
allocator_create_info.instance = *instance;
allocator_create_info.physicalDevice = physical_device;
allocator_create_info.device = *device;
allocator_create_info.vulkanApiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_2;
VmaAllocator allocator = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
if (vmaCreateAllocator(
    &allocator_create_info, &allocator
) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    abort();
}

VmaAllocationCreateInfo staging_buffer_alloc_info = {};
staging_buffer_alloc_info.usage = VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_CPU_TO_GPU;
VkBufferCreateInfo buffer_create_info =
    vk::BufferCreateInfo()
    //1024バイトの
    .setSize(1024)
    .setUsage(
        vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eTransferSrc |
        vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eTransferDst
    );
VkBuffer staging_buffer;
VmaAllocation staging_buffer_allocation;
if (vmaCreateBuffer(
    allocator,
    &buffer_create_info,
    &staging_buffer_alloc_info,
    &staging_buffer,
    &staging_buffer_allocation,
    nullptr
) != VK_SUCCESS) abort();

void* mapped_memory = nullptr;
if (vmaMapMemory(
    allocator, staging_buffer_allocation, &mapped_memory
) != VK_SUCCESS) abort();
auto begin = reinterpret_cast<float*>(mapped_memory);
auto end = std::next(begin, 1024 / sizeof(float));
std::fill(begin, end, 0.0f);
```

The results of calcuration are in staging_buffer(VkBuffer).
How to get values from it and How do I use std::cout to output?

```
void* mapped;
float* a = (float*)malloc(1024);
vmaMapMemory(allocator,staging_buffer_allocation,&mapped);
memcpy(a, mapped, 1024);
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

This program is not works. This program's output is 000001B2A6D651C0.

Answer (score 0):

> std::cout << a << std::endl;

This is printing out the address of your float array.  If you want to actually print out the contents of the array you need to dereference the pointer.

What happens if you call `std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;`?

Also, you're mapping the memory in each code block but we don't see what happens in between.  Are you unmapping the memory?  Are you flushing the memory (that's required if the memory doesn't have the property `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT` bit)?

If you're running a compute shader, are you putting in the required synchronization barriers between the creation of the shader, the compute buffer and the reading of the shader?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This program worked, after I changed to "std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;".